# iOS CoreBluetooth virtual peripheral multiple notifications

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, bluetooth-gatt

I am working on an iOS application where I need to send more than 20 bytes of data to a Bluetooth LE central. I have set up a peripheral manager and I send each "packet" of 20 bytes one after the other. I only send the next packet once `peripheralManager.updatevalue` returns true (I retry after `peripheralManagerIsReadyToUpdateSubscribers` is called if `updateValue` returns false). Most of the time this works, however about 20% of the time the data that is sent is incorrect.

I have three packets. Most of the time the central receives A then B then C, however sometimes the central receives B then B again then C or A then C then C again.

It is always sending three notifications, however the values are incorrect.

In case it is important:

The values for a characteristic are stored in instances of `BLECharacteristic` objects

```
@objc public class BLECharacteristic: CBMutableCharacteristic{
    public var dynamicValue: Data?
    public override init(type UUID: CBUUID, properties: CBCharacteristicProperties, value: Data?, permissions: CBAttributePermissions){
        super.init(type: UUID, properties: properties, value: nil, permissions: permissions)
        self.dynamicValue = value
    }
    public convenience init(characteristic: CBCharacteristic){
        self.init(type: characteristic.uuid, properties: characteristic.properties, value: characteristic.value, permissions: CBAttributePermissions.readable)
    }
}
```

And when notifications are "buffered" to be sent after `peripheralManagerIsReadyToUpdateSubscribers` is called the info is stored in a `DelayedNotification` object.

```
@objc public class DelayedNotification: NSObject{
    private(set) var valueToNotify: Data
    private(set) var characteristic: BLECharacteristic
    private(set) var devicesToNotify: [CBCentral]?

    @objc public init(_ data: Data, _ char: BLECharacteristic, _ devsNotify: [CBCentral]?){
        valueToNotify = data
        characteristic = char
        devicesToNotify = devsNotify
    }
}
```

When the object is created:

```
var valueToSend: Data
if(characteristic.dynamicValue == nil){
    valueToSend = Data()
}else{
    valueToSend = characteristic.dynamicValue!
}

buffer.append(DelayedNotification(valueToSend, characteristic, devicesToNotify))
```

Edit: More code

```
private func notifyDevices(_ characteristic: BLECharacteristic){
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        var valueToSend: Data
        if(characteristic.dynamicValue == nil){
            valueToSend = Data()
        }else{
            valueToSend = Data(characteristic.dynamicValue!)
        }

        self.notificationLock.wait()
        self.notBuffer.append(DelayedNotification(valueToSend, characteristic, nil))
        self.notificationLock.signal()

        self.processNotificationBuffer()
    }
}

private func processNotificationBuffer(){
    DispatchQueue.main.async{
        self.notificationLock.wait()

        for notification in self.notBuffer{
            let res = self.peripheralManager.updateValue(Data(notification.valueToNotify), for: notification.characteristic, onSubscribedCentrals: notification.devicesToNotify)
            if(res){
                NSLog("Sent: " + String(data: notification.valueToNotify, encoding: .utf8)!) // This is always printed in the right order
                notificationSent()
                self.notBuffer.remove(at: self.notBuffer.index(of: notification)!)
            }
        }

        self.notificationLock.signal()
    }
}

@objc public func peripheralManagerIsReady(toUpdateSubscribers peripheral: CBPeripheralManager) {
    processNotificationBuffer()
}
```

Comment: Where do you assign to `dynamicValue`?  It looks like you are updating an existing `Data` instance that a `DelayedNotification` is holding a reference to, rather than creating a new instance.

Comment: dynamicValue is assigned when a write request is received or when the server is told to write a value to a characteristic. I thought that might be the case, but Data does not seem to have a `copy` method. I tied encoding and decoding to/from base64 to try to create a new instance, but it did not change anything.  `valueToSend = Data(base64Encoded: char.dynamicValue!.base64EncodedData())!` Is there a better/correct way to copy a Data object in swift?

Comment: You don't need a `copy` function; you can simply use the `init(_ data:Data)` initialiser from `Data`

Comment: Ok. Thanks @Paulw11. I tried this, but it did not seem to fix my problem. I still get packets repeated about 1 of every 5-6 attempts.

Comment: You certainly have a threading/timing related issue, but you haven't shown enough code; Where do you actually call `updateValue` on the `CBPeripheralManager` ?  How do you ensure that `buffer` is only updated in a synchronised manner? (You should probably be using a dedicated serial dispatch queue to enforce this).

Comment: When a characteristic is written by the server the dynamicValue is changed. A notifyDevices method is then called. This method will setup the `DelayedNotification` object and add it to the buffer. This happens asynchronously using `DispatchQueue.main.async`. A `processNotificationBuffer` method is then called. This sends notifications from the buffer until `updateValue` returns false. This also uses `DispatchQueue.main.async`. The `processNotificationBuffer` method is also called from `isReady`. I use a `DispatchSemaphore` to ensure that the buffer is not modified in more than one place.

Comment: I can also print the data that is sent when `updateValue` returns true. It prints out correctly in the correct order, but the data that gets sent is still wrong, which seems to indicate that it is still referencing the `dynamicValue` property. When the DelayedNotification object is created I use Data(characteristic.dynamicValue!) as the valueToNotify property. When `updateValue` is called I (again) use Data(notification.valueToNotify). This should (I think) copy the data twice, but it still seems like it is being referenced. Is there another way I could try copying the Data  object?

Comment: Why are you using an asynchronous dispatch on the main queue? Also, potentially blocking the main queue is risky. I still don't understand why you are using this `dynamicValue` property. Wouldn't it be simpler just to have a queue of values to be sent and just process that queue; always use the queue, not just when a writer fails. How many centrals are you connected to? If you are sending larger amounts of data, consider using an L2CAP channel

Comment: Oops. Forgot to change that to the background queue. I have put together a simplified test project that does not use `BLECharacteristic`. I am still having the same problem. The test project is here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1bhN_w1qACHb8fg6Lej4hqd0ppfvjptjC. Unfortunately the client device does not support L2CAP so I cannot use that. While testing I am only connected to one central.

Comment: I downloaded your sample and wrote a simple central that connects, subscribes to the characteristic and prints what it receives. I then changed your app to send the 3 packets every 0.2 seconds.  I received all of the data in the correct order.  Perhaps you have a problem in your central code.

Comment: That's possible. I'm using an Android central using a generic app. I'll write my own and see how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the client. My custom android client works as intended.